# AngularJS: Function to test if has class

Tags: javascript, angularjs, jasmine

On a form submit trying to run a function in a controller that checks for matching passwords and if email field contains a class.

Scenerios:

If the passwords don't match it fails

If email contains `ng-invalid` it fails

Passwords validate just fine, the issue is trying to see if the Email field contains a class after form submit.

In jQuery would write:

`if($(#email).hasClass('ng-invalid'){//email is invalid man return false;}`

But in Angular not using jQuery. Tried several ways in vanilla JS to see if #email has class 'ng-invalid' but it's not working. [JavaScript Check If Element Has Class](http://sonnyt.com/javascript-check-if-element-has-class/)

The end result is using the function "formValidate()" in Jasmine unit test to verify if formValidate() is true or false.

Basic Implementation:

[PLUNKER](http://plnkr.co/edit/8O2CeYddLvXtdOmRsyJO?p=preview)

Jasmine (This should fail):

```
it('Join Now button should be enabled when form fields are valid.',          

function(){ 
  var ctrl = createController();
  $httpBackend.flush();
  var joinNowBtn = registrationEl.find('.join-now-btn');

$rootScope.user = {
  'email': 'hola@friend.c',
  'password': 'abc',
  'passwordConfirm': 'abc'
};

expect($rootScope.formValidate()).toBeTruthy(); //THIS TEST SHOULD FAIL

//expect submit button to not have a disabled attribute
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to check for `ng-invalid` class. Just check if `$scope.registration_form.email.$invalid` is `true` or `false`.

`$scope.user.email.$invalid` didn't work because `$scope.user.email` is just a string.

Form validation information is put into `$scope.formName`. You can use the following:

```
$scope.formName.$invalid === true
$scope.formName.fieldName.$invalid === true
```

Check [NgModelController docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/ngModel.NgModelController).

Comment: Thanks, `if ($scope.registration_form.email.$invalid)` took care of it. Not sure why I was stuck on "$scope.user.email".

Comment: Accept as answered if it solved your problem so we have less unanswered questions in SO :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `hasClass()`

Angular natively has access to jqLite's `hasClass()`.

http://docs.angularjs.org/api/angular.element

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't need to be checking classes a la jQuery. You can check the validity of the form input by passing the form into your submit function and checking to see if `email.$invalid` is true or false. So something like this:

**html**

```
ng-submit="submitForm(this.registration_form)"
```

**js function**

```
$scope.formValidate = function(form){
    if(form.email.$invalid){
      alert('email is invaid')
      return;
    }
    // etc.
}
```